patch: do not remove empty ancestor directories
I need to merge changes between directories into a third directory. I am using patch to merge the files and a custom script to merge the empty directories (mkdir/rmdir). Unfortunately patch will remove empty ancestor directories when removing empty output files. Removing empty output files is required for proper merging, but removing empty ancestor directories breaks merging. How can I prevent patch from removing empty ancestor directories?
Example:
$ rm -rf a b 3.a
$ mkdir -p a/dir{01..02}
$ cp -r a b
$ touch a/dir01/file{00..05}
$ for i in a/dir01/file{00..04}; do dd if=/dev/random bs=128 count=4 status=none | base64 >"$i"; done
$ echo -e "foo" >a/dir02/file01
$ cp -a a 3.a
$ git diff --no-prefix a b >git.diff
$ tree -ahN
  # contrast with 'patch --posix --remove-empty-files ...':
$ patch -d 3.a/ -p1 -i../git.diff --verbose |& grep -i "^Removed empty directory"
$ tree -ahN

.
├── [   0]  3.a
│   ├── [   0]  dir01
│   │   ├── [ 693]  file00
│   │   ├── [ 693]  file01
│   │   ├── [ 693]  file02
│   │   ├── [ 693]  file03
│   │   ├── [ 693]  file04
│   │   └── [   0]  file05
│   └── [   0]  dir02
│       └── [   4]  file01
├── [   0]  a
│   ├── [   0]  dir01
│   │   ├── [ 693]  file00
│   │   ├── [ 693]  file01
│   │   ├── [ 693]  file02
│   │   ├── [ 693]  file03
│   │   ├── [ 693]  file04
│   │   └── [   0]  file05
│   └── [   0]  dir02
│       └── [   4]  file01
├── [   0]  b
│   ├── [   0]  dir01
│   └── [   0]  dir02
└── [4.3K]  git.diff

9 directories, 15 files
Removed empty directory dir01
Removed empty directory dir02
.
├── [   0]  3.a
├── [   0]  a
│   ├── [   0]  dir01
│   │   ├── [ 693]  file00
│   │   ├── [ 693]  file01
│   │   ├── [ 693]  file02
│   │   ├── [ 693]  file03
│   │   ├── [ 693]  file04
│   │   └── [   0]  file05
│   └── [   0]  dir02
│       └── [   4]  file01
├── [   0]  b
│   ├── [   0]  dir01
│   └── [   0]  dir02
└── [4.3K]  git.diff

7 directories, 8 files


I'm not quite sure what your desired output is but, perhaps you could tell patch to backup the files so that the directories can't be removed, then delete them afterwards. For example:
...
patch -b -z .DELETEME -d 3.a/ ...
find 3.a/ -name '*.DELETEME' -exec rm -v {} +
...

